# .htaccess php progress

Tags: url, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Thanks to the people that've helped me so far with this, I'm ready for the last step, I think.

I've got my URLs looking like this.

```
/brochure.php?cat_path=35&name=concrete-intermediate-posts
```

This is great and finally I just need to know how to turn that URL into this desired URL:

```
/brochure/35/concrete-intermediate-posts
```

Just like the Stack Overflow format.

Could anyone help me with the correct .htaccess rule?

Also, if I have other get variables in other sections, will this re-write harm them?   (they use different variable names)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mod_rewrite you will rather do the opposite: rewrite a URL path like `/brochure/35/concrete-intermediate-posts` internally to `/brochure.php?cat_path=35&name=concrete-intermediate-posts`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?cat_path=$2&name=$3 [L,QSA]
```

The other side, using a URL path like `/brochure/35/concrete-intermediate-posts` instead of `/brochure.php?cat_path=35&name=concrete-intermediate-posts` in the HTML documents, would be done with PHP.

Comment: That's thrown me a little, what result would this produce? my desired one?

Comment: @shane: No. The mentioned rule will only allow to also request the resource of `/brochure.php?cat_path=35&name=concrete-intermediate-posts` with `/brochure/35/concrete-intermediate-posts`.

Comment: Ok that's great, thanks. So I first need to create my desired URL, and then use your code to allow it to make the correct requests?

Comment: How would I go about changing the URL with PHP?

Comment: @shane: Yep. I don’t know how you generate these URLs. But you just need to change the format so that the output looks like `/brochure/35/concrete-intermediate-posts`.

Comment: I create /brochure.php?cat_path=35&name=concrete-intermediate-posts

Comment: I create /brochure.php?cat_path=35&name=concrete-intermediate-posts with msql calls for the ID and Name, and then I run the name through a function to create the 'concrete-intermediate-posts' part.

Comment: Scratch that. It's just returning 'page not found' as if the rewrite rule isn't kicking in/  Any common reasons for this? (host?)

Comment: @shane: Do you use the obligatory `RewriteEngine on`?

Comment: Am I using the correct method to get this working. I've replaced my links with   <a href="/brochure/29/concrete-posts">link<a/>.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope you mean something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^brochure/([0-9]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /brochure.php?cat_path=$1&name=$2 [L]
```